# How to edit packages before install?

Tags: package-management

On Arch, I could just makepkg -s and get the files I needed to change, then makepkg -sci. I'm sure the same can be accomplished on Ubuntu for those who want to alter the code to suit their needs like dmenu or i3-wm for me so the i3bar and dmenu look the same. Is there a wiki on Ubuntu I could find to do this or what would I need to install? Many thinks for reading and hope to find an answer soon :-)